# Match float numbers separated by semicolon

Tags: regex, qregexp

I use a regexp validator and I want to restrict the use of anything but the pattern:

`5414.1;123;412.1;41241;`...

I tried to use `[0-9;\.]*` but I can't make it match only patterns which contain one(1) point after the text and before `;`.

I tested using `http://regexpal.com/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not perfect, too, but is already in the near... for example it allowed -01.5.

```
((-|)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*[1-9]|)\;)*(-|)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*[1-9]|)
```

Instead an `(x|)` -like expression you can also use `x?`. (Thanks @OGHaza)

Comment: Might be nitpicking but using `x?` seems much clearer than `(x|)`.

Answer (score 4):

If the data has to end with a `;`:

```
 (-?\d+(\.\d+)?\;)+
```

Otherwise:

```
 (-?\d+(\.\d+)?)(;-?\d+(\.\d+)?)*;?
```

These will not allow empty input but you can achieve that behaviour by replacing the `+` in the first example with `*` and by wrapping the second one in `(...)?`.

Answer (score 4):

```
^(\d+(\.\d+)?;)+$
```

the `^$` will prevent accepting a part of the string

Answer (score 2):

you could also use this pattern

```
^(?:-?\d+[.;]?)+$
```